# How to integrate .traineddata from trainyourtesseract.com?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ocr, tesseract

I have successfully trained my tesseract using Anyline's [trainyourtesseract](https://www.anyline.io/blog/2016/08/16/train-your-tesseract/) and got a .traineddata file in my email. I might be asking a dumb question here but do you simply drag this to your tessdata folder and cross your fingers and hopefully it works. The are no directions to integrate it. I have seen tutorials that integrate two different languages with a code line like this.

```
G8Tesseract *operation = [[G8Tesseract alloc] init];
operation.language = @"eng+fra";
```

So I tried to do the following code but it gave me an cube error.

```
G8Tesseract *operation = [[G8Tesseract alloc] init];
operation.language = @"eng+arial";
```

The name of the .traineddata file that I got was `arial.traineddata`.

Running the code above I tried to implement throws an error

```
"Cube ERROR (CubeRecoContext::Load): unable to read cube language model params from /var/containers/Bundle/Application/98165164-BA09-40FE-AF82-7CAAE9B77F45/ExWU.app/tessdata/arial.cube.lm
Cube ERROR (CubeRecoContext::Create): unable to init CubeRecoContext object"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to initialize G8Tesseract in G8OCREngineModeTesseractOnly and see if this works.

```
__block G8Tesseract * operation = [[G8Tesseract alloc]initWithLanguage:@"eng+arial" engineMode:G8OCREngineModeTesseractOnly];
```